# How to disable multiple instance in python-vlc?

Tags: python, python-vlc

I'm new to python vlc so I'm not sure if I'm asking the right question. That being said what I want to do is for example if I run the code below twice the initial instance will stop (i.e the song will stop playing automatically).

```
def mediaPlayer():
    instance = vlc.Instance('--play-and-exit')
    url=[song1.mp3,song2.mp3]
    media_list = instance.media_list_new(url)
    list_player = instance.media_list_player_new()            
    list_player.set_media_list(media_list)
    list_player.play()
```

Comment: run it using threads

Comment: vlc instances are already being run from threads...  Aren't they?